# How to start On Boarding activity after Splash Screen activity in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, splash-screen

I've made a splash screen(Introductory activity) using Cuberto Liquid Pager. My next activity is supposed to be an on boarding activity where 3 fragments are there. The problem is after running the code, Splash screen & 1st fragment from onboarding activity are getting merged. I've tried different solutions but nothing has worked. Please shed some light on this problem.

IntroductoryActivity.java

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_introductory);


    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    h1= findViewById(R.id.houseintro);
    h2= findViewById(R.id.houseintro2);
    bottom= findViewById(R.id.bottom);
    txt1= findViewById(R.id.atsingleplace);
    txt2= findViewById(R.id.findallprop);
    appname= findViewById(R.id.findmehome);




    h1.animate().translationY(-2000).setDuration(1000).setStartDelay(6000);
    h2.animate().translationY(2000).setDuration(1000).setStartDelay(6000);
    bottom.animate().translationY(3000).setDuration(1000).setStartDelay(6000);
    txt2.animate().translationY(2000).setDuration(1000).setStartDelay(6000);
    txt1.animate().translationY(2000).setDuration(1000).setStartDelay(6000);
    appname.animate().translationY(2000).setDuration(1000).setStartDelay(6000);


    viewPager=findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pagerAdapter=new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),1);
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
}


private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter  extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{

    @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm, int i) {
        super(fm, FragmentStatePagerAdapter.BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);


    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
                case 0:
                    OnBoardingFragment1 tab1 =new OnBoardingFragment1();
                    return tab1;

                case 1:
                    OnBoardingFragment2 tab2 =new OnBoardingFragment2();
                    return tab2;

                case 2:
                    OnBoardingFragment3 tab3 =new OnBoardingFragment3();
                    return tab3;
            }
            return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return NUM_PAGES;
    }
}
```

}

OnBoardingFragment1.java

```
public class OnBoardingFragment1 extends Fragment {
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup root=(ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_on_boarding1,container,false);
    return root;
    //return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}
```

}

OnBoardingFragment2.java

```
public class OnBoardingFragment2 extends Fragment {
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ViewGroup root=(ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_on_boarding2,container,false);
    return root;
    //return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}
```

}

OnBoardingFragment3

```
public class OnBoardingFragment3 extends Fragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ViewGroup root=(ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_on_boarding3,container,false);
    return root;
    //return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In case you have still not solved it, I think you can use a  viewPager for a separate onboarding screen to swipe through the different layout views and either using different class for the splash or attaching the splash style to the onboarding screen to load before the onboarding screen .